# How do you represent a Hadamard gate as a product of $R_x$ and $R_y$ gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, textbook-and-exercises, hadamard

I'm looking for a representation of Hadamard gate that uses only $R_x(x)$ and $R_y(y)$ gates. The values $x$ and $y$ may be the same, but they don't necessarily need to be.

Comment: You may refer to this [link](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/how-to-visualize-hadamard-gate-as-x-z-x-decomposition).

Comment: possible duplicate: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16651/55

Comment: Hi @user16554! If the [answer of forky40](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18342/1386) answered your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 8):

If you're not concerned with global phase then the following works using only two rotation gates:
\begin{align}
R_y\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) R_x\left(\pi\right) &= \exp \left(i\frac{\pi}{4}Y\right) \exp \left(-i\frac{\pi}{2}X\right)
\\&= \left(\cos \frac{\pi}{4} I + i\sin \frac{\pi}{4} Y\right) \left(-iX\right)
\\&=\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos \frac{\pi}{4} & \sin\frac{\pi}{4} \\
-\sin \frac{\pi}{4} & \cos \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -i \\
-i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\\&= -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\\&= -iH
\end{align}
where $R_x(\theta) = \exp(-i\theta X/2)$ and $R_y(\theta) = \exp(-i\theta Y/2)$.

Comment: Nice answer! Just a quick addition: if you do care about the global phase then it is actually not possible